# Flex - changing order of nested elements?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

On small screens i'm trying to get my `.image` div to slot in between `.title` and `.text` divs, something like:

```
title
image
text
```

.title and .text are wrapped in a container, this is so on a different screen size (medium up) I can do:

```
title | image
text  | continuation of image element
```

I've thought about using a flex column layout for small screens, and changing the order of elements, but order doesn't seem to have an effect on a nested child element.

Here's the code for small:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="text"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
}
.image {
    order: 2;
}
.title {
    order: 1;
}
.text {
    order: 3;
}
```

For reference my code for medium is (cascading upwards from small):

```
.container {
     flex-direction: row;
}
.content {
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
.image {
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

Comment: You cannot achieve your requirement like this. It won't work since the image itself is outside your content div. So it won't workout.

Answer (score 0):

You can ordering only sibling elements. Title and text aren't sibling with image. You need wrap title, text and image in general parent block

Comment: Ok, how can I then achieve my medium layout of title and text stacked and image to the right side of them?

Comment: You need add image element to the container

Comment: Yes - but how do you make the medium layout in doing that?

Comment: Give the title 50% of the body and give the image 50% of the body(using flex-basis) and add to the container flex-wrap: wrap

Comment: Thanks, but doing this leave a massive gap underneath the title.

Comment: What if give the text some width how you give the title? If it doesn't solve your problem please write more code(on codepen or another). I can't understand what you really need without code

Comment: Same issue as it's a row. Code above is sufficient enough to tackle problem.

Comment: You can give the image the height which equals height of your title, this is only way to solve your problem with flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar case, but for solution CSS grid is used, however there is also another support is recommended: [CSS subgrid](https://caniuse.com/css-subgrid)

For a simple design like even columns or rows it is not that hard to replicate, but if parent container contain more complex grid sizes, then CSS subgrid will be requirement for an only CSS solution.

Here is full demo: https://codepen.io/XCanG/pen/vYaNZPo?editors=1100

HTML I have in the demo have very similar structure with having parent, some container for 2 nested elements and 3rd element.

*This is quote from my demo, except I rename class names according to your example:*

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.container .content {
    display: grid;
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1 / span 3;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr); /* Fallback */
    grid-template-rows: subgrid; /* Limited support: https://caniuse.com/css-subgrid */
    grid-template-columns: subgrid;
}
.container .title {
    grid-colimn: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
}
.container .text {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 3;
}
.container .image {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2;
}
```

CSS make that nested element follow grid columns and rows, with subgrid support you will have exactly defined part of the grid (otherwise you will need to define fallback). And with `grid-column` and `grid-row` it is possible to sort elements.

Answer (score 0):

`Grid-template-areas` will come in pretty handy in this type of layout as they are not siblings. And `grid-template-areas` have full browser support.

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "title img"
                         "txt img";
}
.title{grid-area: title;}
.text{grid-area: txt;}
.image{grid-area: img;}

@media(max-width: 800px){
  .container{
    grid-template-areas: 'title'
                         'img'
                         'txt';
                         
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="title">title</div>
        <div class="text">text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">img</div>
</div>
```