# Using floats to align to top?

Tags: css

How can I float two elements left and float the third element right, with the top of the third element being inline with the top of the first element?

```
item 1  item 3
item 2
```

I've tries floating item 1 and item 2 left, and item, 3 right, but then the top of item 3 is only at the top of item 2, like this:

```
item 1  
item 2  item 3
```

HTML:

```
<div class="item1"></div>
<div class="item2"></div>
<div class="item3"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.item1 {
    float:left;
}
.item2 {
    float:left;
}
 .item3 {
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sky2Lhv3/  - modify this ..

Comment: Uses flex, does not answer question.

Comment: Basically, you can't..without changing the HTML

Comment: Why do you have to use floats? Can't you use flex and just use `order` property to reorder the elements?

Comment: I cannot use flex, have explored already in previous questions.

Comment: See the second snippet in my answer, it is using flex and providing the layout you are asking for without markup changes.

Comment: Why do you not mention this in the question then? And if there are limitations to your approach, describe why those limitations are imposed. And please do not refer to previous questions, no one checks all your questions before answering.

Comment: Marko Grešak - Because I cam to the conclusion that a flex box layout was not possible, asked a simple question regarding floats, not flex!

Comment: Nowadays flex is widely used and a reasonable suggestion for a fix to your problem. Your problem is to align the items properly, not to align items using floats and without reordering the elements. I'm asking why is it necessary to use float when there is a better solution. Limiting the solution without a reason sounds like it's some sort of homework or an interview question.

Comment: @panthro The simple answer then is: you can't do it. With floats, #2 needs `clear: left` to be below #1 and at this point, #3 will never be at the same top as #1 (except using absolute positioning or negative margins).

Comment: Marko Grešak if I ask for a question about floats I want an answer about floats. I'm not going to write out the previous question again, which is against SO rules. If you can figure out the issue with flex go ahead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45457974/flex-changing-order-of-nested-elements

Comment: Marko Grešak "Your problem is to align the items properly, not to align items using floats" please see title of question - Using floats to align to top?

Answer (score 2):

Use clear both to second element and place your second .item2 after third

```css
.item1 {
    float:left;
}
.item2 {
    float:left;
    clear: both;
}
 .item3 {
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="item1">1</div>
<div class="item3">3</div>
<div class="item2">2</div>
```

Comment: That's the obvious solution, but will not work if you do not have the full control of markup.

Comment: yes, you're right but since he didn't mention anything about the markup I answered assuming he can change the html.

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code

```css
.main {
  float:left;
}

.item3 {
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="main">
  <div class="item1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item2">Item 2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item3">Item 3</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

here's a simple solution... just use and clearfix property after item 1 like this one

```css
.item1 {
    float:left;
}
.item2 {
    float:left;
}
 .item3 {
    float:right;
}

div{
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:grey;
}

.clearfix{
  display:block;
  background:transparent;
  clear:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="item1">A</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="item2">B</div>
<div class="item3">C</div>
```

`

Answer (score -2):

*Note: The original question didn't state anything of clearing.*

If floating the items *without any clearance*, it should work right away, see example below.

```css
#one {
  width: 150px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #fc0;
  float: left;
}

#two {
  width: 120px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #09f;
  float: left;
}

#three {
  width: 100px;
  height: 130px;
  background: #3c6;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="one">#1</div>
<div id="two">#2</div>
<div id="three">#3</div>
</div>
```

If you do want element #2 to be **below** #1 and #3 still be at the right side aligned with #1, you should either switch #2 and #3's places and apply a `clear: both;` to #2 (see answer by Saravanan I) or add a wrapping element around #1 and #2 (see comment by bhv).

As an alternative and if markup changes are not possible, you can use flexbox instead of floats, it allows you to order the elements, see example below.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
#container > div {
  flex-basis: 34%;
}
#one {
  background: #fc0;
  order: 1;
}

#two {
  background: #09f;
  order: 3;
}

#three {
  background: #3c6;
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="one">#1<br>some short text</div>
<div id="two">#2<br>other text, should be directly below #1</div>
<div id="three">#3<br>Oh boy,<br>this is much longer.<br>Will it break the layout?<br>#2 is supposed to be<br>right next to #1.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flex solution does not work, as any increase in height to #3 pushes #2 down the page. #2 should sit directly under #1. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, taking background color in my second snippet into account, #2 is directly adjacent to #1 even though #3 has longer text.

Comment: Please fill up #3 with a decent amount of text - then youll see it doesnt work.

Comment: Ah you have updated your example - see it doesnt work. #2 text is not directly below #1 text. Lots of yellow here!

Comment: That's why I said "taking background color into account". You will need `flex-direction: column` for that but as you stated in your previous question, you may not apply a height to the parent container. Thus, the answer is: it's not possible without markup changes.

Comment: Thnaks Paul, even tho its not . solution least i have an answer its not possible with flex, why i now switched to floats.